# Trackpad on M1 Macbook Pro causing intermittent problems

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, ventura

I've got a Macbook Pro 2021 running Ventura 13.2.1. Not had any problems with the trackpad until recently. Problem seems to be getting worse.

When I two finger scroll on Pages, or Firefox, I notice that on occassion the page will leap up an inch or so quite suddenly. It can be really distracting when I'm trying to read, scrolling down gently and the page suddenly leaps up half a paragraph.

The worst problem is inside Blender. I use the two finger scroll to orbit around the object. The object will rotate and then instantaneously zoom in by about 15% or more. Not so much of a zoom as an instant cut closer in. I'm fairly certain that this problem is getting worse as time goes on.

I tried switching off Natural scrolling and other scrolling functions in the Trackpad settings but it's always the same.

Comment: Has the trackpad got hit by something before?

Comment: No. And in answering this I have to place twelve more words apparantly or it won't post.

Comment: Haha xD yes... 15 characters minimum and 600 maximum for comments xD